# How to increase the number of folders shown in the quick bookmark list in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I often use the quick bookmark folder list in Firefox to choose where to place a bookmark, but with the number of folders that I have, I quickly run into the 7 folder limit that they have on the drop down and then have to manually search for the folder. Is there a way to increase the number of folders shown?

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering this! I hate the small editDialog with a passion, never got used to it despite all the years. It's just impossible to browse a tree of dozens or hundreds of folders with a minuscule panel which only shows 7 at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an easy way to do this finally. Go to about:config in your address bar and search for the setting browser.bookmarks.editDialog.maxRecentFolders and set this to the desired number (don't go crazy with it). You don't have to restart your browser for the change to take effect. It won't instantly increase the number of folders shown, you'll have to start adding to folders and it will gradually increase the number shown up to the max you specify as you bookmark items in the future.